# Ayuda error al subir mi proyecto django a heroku

Tags: django, heroku

Hola a todos he buscado mil tutoriales, lei la documentación oficial, pero me he encontrado con muchos errores, y este es el ultimo que me ha arrojado justo cuando se esta subiendo mi aplicacion.

```
Collecting setuptools
  Using cached setuptools-38.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: setuptools
  Found existing installation: setuptools 35.0.2
    Uninstalling setuptools-35.0.2:
      Successfully uninstalled setuptools-35.0.2
Successfully installed setuptools-38.4.0

(venv) C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\curriculum>git push heroku master
Counting objects: 52, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (42/42), done.
Writing objects: 100% (52/52), 4.80 MiB | 304.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 52 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing python-3.6.4
remote: -----> Installing pip
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Collecting dj-database-url==0.4.2 (from -r /tmp/build_68663a578d47190d4464e28e3da2d0bc/requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:          Downloading dj_database_url-0.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting gunicorn==19.7.1 (from -r /tmp/build_68663a578d47190d4464e28e3da2d0bc/requirements.txt (line 2))
remote:          Downloading gunicorn-19.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (111kB)
remote:        Collecting whitenoise==3.3.1 (from -r /tmp/build_68663a578d47190d4464e28e3da2d0bc/requirements.txt (line 3))
remote:          Downloading whitenoise-3.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting psycopg2==2.6.2 (from -r /tmp/build_68663a578d47190d4464e28e3da2d0bc/requirements.txt (line 4))
remote:          Downloading psycopg2-2.6.2.tar.gz (376kB)
remote:            Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
remote:            running egg_info
remote:            creating pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info
remote:            writing pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
remote:            writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
remote:            writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
remote:            writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
remote:            Error: could not determine PostgreSQL version from '10.1'
remote:
remote:            ----------------------------------------
remote:        Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-fi31chu0/psycopg2/
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que estás usando una versión muy vieja de `psycopg2` que no tiene soporte para PostgreSQL 10.X. Probá instalando la versión más nueva de `psycopg2` (es posible que tengas que editar tu archivo de requerimientos).